# How to fix the error ? IndentationError: unexpected indent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, trading

I was trying to run the code from : https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/the-supertrend-implementing-screening-backtesting-in-python-70e8f88f383d

but when it came to this block I saw that there was an error that i've not been able to fix.

It shows IndentationError: unexpected indent. How to fix this?

```
def find_optimal_parameter(df):
    # predefine several parameter sets
    atr_period = [7, 8, 9, 10]
    atr_multiplier = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
roi_list = []

# for each period and multiplier, perform backtest
    for period, multiplier in [(x,y) for x in atr_period for y in atr_multiplier]:
        new_df = df
        supertrend = Supertrend(df, period, multiplier)
        new_df = df.join(supertrend)
        new_df = new_df[period:]
        entry, exit, roi = backtest_supertrend(new_df, 100000)
        roi_list.append((period, multiplier, roi))
    
    print(pd.DataFrame(roi_list, columns=['ATR_period','Multiplier','ROI']))
    
    # return the best parameter set
    return max(roi_list, key=lambda x:x[2])
df = yf.download('TSLA', start='2010-01-01')

optimal_param = find_optimal_parameter(df)

print(f'Best parameter set: ATR Period={optimal_param[0]}, Multiplier={optimal_param[1]}, ROI={optimal_param[2]}')
```

Comment: python is sensitive to indentation. your code is not indented correctly and that gives you an error. you need to fix your indentation to fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a tab or 4 spaces in front of `roi_list = []`

Edit: As chris pointed out, 4 spaces are recommended by [python style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Comment: what if the rest of the code is indented using spaces?

Comment: Then he should use 4 spaces if i'm correct.

Comment: Please don't recommend tabs for Python development. The [official style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends four spaces. Though the most important thing is to match the rest of the indentation in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because python is heavily sensitive to indentation, unlike other languages, you need to make sure that all lines are indented correctly and uniformly.

On line 5 of this code, place a tab or four spaces in front of the text, and you should get no error.

An easy way to tell where this error is is to read the error output and determine what line the error was thrown on and then look at that line to see if the code is indented properly.